# Map/convert to a parent property from a list nested multiple levels deep with Automapper

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm trying to use Automapper to map my data model which looks like this:

```
User
 -> UserRoles // list<UserRole> - has a prop for User and Role
  -> Role 
   -> RolePermissions // list<RolePermission> - has a prop for Role and Permission
    -> Permission
```

To a simplified model as DTOs for a web service that looks like this:

```
UserDto
 -> Roles // List<RoleDto>
 -> Permissions // List<PermissionDto>
```

As you can see the first model is a relational model from a database - it has a couple levels of many-to-many relationships that I would like to be more User-centric and aggregate all the permissions across all the roles that user has access to.

I've managed to get the UserDto with Roles property mapped from User -> UserRoles -> Roles, but the aggregation of the Permissions is really causing me to bang my head against the desk (and I cant think 2 gud, so I need help)

Here's my code for mapping to the Roles, it seems to work.

```
CreateMap<RoleDto, UserRole>()
    .ForMember(x => x.Role, y => y.MapFrom(z => z))
    .ReverseMap();

CreateMap<UserRole, RoleDto>()
    .ForMember(x => x.RoleId, y => y.MapFrom(z => z.Role.RoleId))
    .ForMember(x => x.Name, y => y.MapFrom(z => z.Role.Name))
    .ReverseMap();

CreateMap<User, UserDto>() 
    .ForMember(x => x.Roles, y => y.MapFrom(z => z.UserRoles))
    // NOT SURE HOW TO MAP THIS NEXT LINE --->
    //.ForMember(x => x.Permissions, y => y.MapFrom(z => z.UserRoles)) 
    .ReverseMap();
```

How can I aggregate all the (unique) permissions across all the roles that a user is enrolled to into a single property under the user?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that your domain structure is:

```
public class User {
    public List<UserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
}

public class UserRole {
    public Role Role { get; set; }
}

public class Role {
    public List<RolePermission> RolePermissions { get; set; }
}

public class RolePermission {
    public Permission Permission { get; set; }
}

public class Permission {
    public string MyPermission { get; set; }
}
```

You can make a next mapping:

```
CreateMap<Permission, PermissionDto>
   // Do your mapping of permissions
   .ForMember(...)'

CreateMap<User, UserDto>() 
    .ForMember(x => x.Roles, y => y.MapFrom(z => z.UserRoles))
    .ForMember(x => x.Permissions, y => y.MapFrom(z => z.UserRoles.Select(e=>e.Role).SelectMany(e=>e.RolePermissions).Select(e=>e.Permission).Distinct(e=>e.MyPermission))) 
    .ReverseMap();
```

Comment: Ahh I think this makes sense!  I was having a hard time figuring out where the logic would come in for the second relationship and was trying to do all kinds of weird "CreateMap" calls to get from Point A to Point C. I forget that MapFrom isn't simply a dumb property or something, it takes a delegate that can be filled with all kinds of code'y goodness.  Trying now, will report back in a few.  Thanks!

Comment: This is perfect, I was able to get it working with your code here.  And you made it look so easy!  I had a real "duhhh" moment, thanks!  The only addition I added, for my own requirements was just a .Distinct() at the end of the lambdas to prevent duplicate permissions.

Comment: You are welcome. Yeap, it makes sense to have a .Distinct() at the end, I will adjust an answer.